# IE Version Control JScript Html

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

We use IE version check in html JavaScript, it works well upto IE9 but no luck with IE10 & IE11 
       Could you please help me extend above so that it works on IE10 & IE11. Or perhaps bypass/ignore it entirely (Tried commenting no luck)

Thanks & Best Regards,
  KSN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try extracting MSIE from the UserAgent string

```
 function msieversion() {
      var ua = window.navigator.userAgent
      var msie = ua.indexOf ( "MSIE " )

      if ( msie > 0 )      // If Internet Explorer, return version number
         return parseInt (ua.substring (msie+5, ua.indexOf (".", msie )))
      else                 // If another browser, return 0
         return 0
 }
```

Comment: Hi Samuil - Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

```
function load( ) {
  valid_browser = false;
  userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
  i = userAgent.indexOf('Trident');
  if (i != -1) {
          valid_browser = true;
      }
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Hi - Webserver didnt have a clue while using MSIE but with trident it picks up latest version.